# NPM Proxy Authntication Falied

Tags: angular, npm, proxy

I m trying to issue the npm install command for getting dependencies for my angular project. I m behind proxy.

to configure .npmrc file I used 
https-proxy=http:// userName : password @ proxy address :8080

but After I useed npm install its getting  below Error

npm ERR! code E407
npm ERR! 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happened because of the proxy that company is using . they are blocking node modules being downloaded.